# Confusion over javascript .map() is able to modify the original array instead of assigning a transformation of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, reference, array.prototype.map

So I was working on some code and noticed that the person prior was modifying the original array by reference and how I thought the .map() function in javascript works by returning a new copy with the modifications returned within the map.

The code below shows how the function is assigning to the array.

```
async assignProductCategoriesToOrders(orders) {
    const { selectedOrganisation } = this.props;

    const response = await Fetcher.get(ProductsService
      .ProductCategories.format(selectedOrganisation.id));

    if (!response.ok) {
      orders.map((order) => order.products.map((product) => {
        product.productCategory = { name: 'N/A' };
        return product;
      }));
    } else {
      const productCategories = await response.json();
      orders.map((order) => order.products.map((product) => {
         product.productCategory = productCategories.find((p) => p.id === product.productCategory)
       || { name: 'N/A' };
         return product;
      }));
   }

   return orders;
}
```

when the orders array is passed in it looks like so

[image]

and once it's through the function it looks like this

[image]

So it's reassigning the new productCategory object to the existing array without returning the maps from the function.

Thanks in advance, would be great to know how this is working.

Comment: Please post code examples as text instead of screenshots.

Comment: `map` does return a new array, but if your array contains references to nested objects or arrays, those may be mutated.

Comment: `map` returns an array but in the callback function it is clear that the dev is **modifying the existing object** and also not storing the new map array in any variable. The dev is using map to only iterate, which is fine.

Comment: Check out the explanation portion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59738588/9381601) for the reason why you are accidentally modifying nested values

Comment: The op meant to use `forEach`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functional array methods in JavaScript (`map(), reduce(), filter(), etc`) all return new objects. None work directly on the array the method is called on.

However, objects in JavaScript are passed by reference. And `map()` (and the other methods) only create a **shallow copy** of the array they are called on. So if that array is composed of objects, then the copy of the array that `map()` uses has references to those same objects.

A quick code example demonstrates this.

```
const foo = ['a', 'b'];
foo.map(itm => { 
   itm = 'c';
   return itm;
}
console.dir(foo)   // still ['a', 'b']

const bar = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'b'}];
bar.map(itm => {
   itm.id = 'c';
   return itm;
}
console.dir(bar)   // the referenced objects were updated [{id: 'c'}, {id: 'c'}]
```

The second example uses `map()` to produce a *side-effect* which generally goes against the idea of functional programming. And your co-worker is doing the same thing with his calls to `orders.map()`. His/her inner function is transforming the properties of the individual order objects that are held and referenced by the cloned orders array. Using `map()` without assigning its return value is a code smell to most JavaScript programmers.

Instead, the code should be using [array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which **is** designed for side effects and has no return value. The syntax for `forEach()` is almost identical to `map()`, and it could be used as a drop-in replacement in your example above.