# React DOM not updating on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, codesandbox

I have a react component that will accept an arbitrary number of files, each with its own language. I want to be able to have a button that lets a user add as many files as they want, each with its own dropdown menu of languages. I've eliminated the file upload for now as I isolate the issue I'm having.

I've created quite a few similar components already without a problem, but for some reason I'm having major trouble with this one. When I change the language on the dropdown, I console log state and see that the language has updated in state, but it does not update on the DOM in my map method.

Here is my code

```
function App() {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

  const languages = ["English", "Spanish", "Arabic", "French"];

  const handleAddFile = e => {
    let newFiles = files;
    newFiles.push({
      content: null,
      preview: null,
      language: ""
    });
    setFiles(newFiles);
  };

  const changeLanguage = (event, index) => {
    let newFiles = files;
    newFiles[index].language = event.target.value;
    setFiles(newFiles);
  };

  console.log(files);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Files</p>
      <p>Upload a file for as many languages as you have</p>
      {files.map((file, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>current language: {file.language}</p>
          <select
            value={file.language}
            onChange={event => changeLanguage(event, index)}
          >
            <option value="" disabled>
              Select a language
            </option>
            {languages.map((lang, i) => (
              <option value={lang} key={i}>
                {lang}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      ))}
      <button onClick={e => handleAddFile(e)}>+ Add File</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've also made a codesandbox to reproduce the issue, but it actually further complicated things. When I run the code locally, I am able to add file instances just fine, but the language on the select element does not update on the DOM for any instance. In the codesandbox, nothing updates on the DOM unless I make an edit in the editor, then everything updates just as I'd expect, including the language. In all cases state is console logged exactly as I'd expect it to be. The component in the sandbox is identical to what I have locally, though locally it is embedded in another component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ed4fx?file=/src/App.js:0-1248

Comment: I have forked your codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-gagarin-il35g?file=/src/App.js, let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @7evam Both `handleAddFile` and `changeLanguage` mutate state. This will prevent a re-render because react will not see the state has changed.

Comment: I have added the code update part and explanation in the  answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in both methods `handleAddFile` and `changeLanguage`, you are directly accessing the state value files, so for updating you need to take the copy and do the changes and set the new values.

Updates you need to do in both methods

```js
let newFiles = files;
```

To

```js
let newFiles = [...files];
```

As @Brian Suggests, when you update deep nested values like language in the `changeLanguage` method. you can do something as shown below so it won't mutate the state.

```js
const changeLanguage = (event, index) => {
  let newFiles = [...files];
  newFiles[index] = { ...newFiles[index], language: event.target.value };
  setFiles(newFiles);
};
```

Check this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-gagarin-il35g)

Better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738516/component-wont-update-when-a-redux-state-change-occurs/59738588#59738588)

Comment: `changeLanguage` should also account for deeply nested state values. Even after correctly destructuring `files`, doing `newFiles[index].language = event.target.value;` will mutate the nested object (even though it probably won't prevent a re-render)

Comment: yes that works! I knew I couldn't directly mutate state but I see now that I unknowingly was. thanks for the help!

Comment: [In this answer, under the Explanation heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738516/component-wont-update-when-a-redux-state-change-occurs/59738588#59738588) is a pretty detailed explanation of how to make true copies of objects (and arrays) in JS

Comment: @BrianThompson , I hope this is what you were expecting , correct me on this will add on the answer
   let newFiles = [...files];
    let currentFile = newFiles[index];
    const { value } = event.target
    currentFile = {...currentFile, language: value};
    newFiles[index] = currentFile
    setFiles(newFiles);

Comment: It seems unnecessarily complex, but I think it works

Comment: as you suggested updated it, even i also initially thought but for better way of understanding you are free to update it. For future references it will be easy

Comment: cool and thanks added the link for explanation part you have. Happy coding :) #stay home #stay safe