# Why this way of non-mutating works in React.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to understand why this example is a good idea.
I'm learning React and I found this function which changes the `complete` property from `todo`.
My question is why this would work? Because we have the const `todo` which is the one being changed in reality, not the `newTodoList` which is the one that we return back. I'm guessing that the respective `todo` from `newTodoList` is changed as well somehow but I don't undertand how this works because again, we changed the newly created `const todo`

```
function toggleTodo(id){
    const newTodoList = [...todos] 
    const todo = newTodoList.find(todo => todo.id === id)
    todo.complete = !todo.complete
    setTodos(newTodoList)
  }
```

Comment: It has to do with how JavaScript objects (and arrays) work. This technically mutates state, which is bad, but since it mutates a nested object it does not affect React's ability to re-render. It is also why it is able to modify the new state while only mutating the old state.

Comment: @Brian Thompson
the state is `[...todos]` so from what I understood it doesn't mutate it, it makes a clone

Comment: It makes a *shallow* clone. Nested objects/arrays are not new instances, they retain the same object references. There's some running examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59738516/component-wont-update-when-a-redux-state-change-occurs/59738588#59738588) (under "Explanation") that may help show what I mean.

Comment: That's helpful thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN Web Docs on `const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), The `const` declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable—just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in the case where the content is an object, this means the object's contents (e.g., its properties) can be altered.

Since `const todo` is an object, you can change its properties (i.e. `todo.complete`)

Comment: So I 'm understanding that `const todo` holds a reference to a value from `newTodoList` so then when we change the `complete` property we actually change it in `newTodoList` through this

Comment: Yes, you are correct. `const newTodoList = [...todos]` creates an array of objects So, `const todo` holds a reference to an object from `newTodoList`. So when you change the `complete` property in `todo`, it also changes it in `newTodoList`.